# best way to access Web Service hosted in JBOSS 5.0.GA + Apache 2.2.2 from WCF .Net 3.5?

Tags: .net, wcf, apache, web-services, jboss5.x

We are in a position to consume the Web Service hosted in JBOSS as explained above.

We tried to generate proxy classes using VS 2008, but we are not successful in calling the Web Services using WCF.

Please share your views?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit light on details but here is a suggestion anyway...

Make sure that you start with the simplest setup first.

1. use basicHttp binding
2. make sure the service is on http (ie not https)

If still not working create service method that returns a simple boolean and takes no parameters. See if you can get that working first.

Once you have this simplest case working, then start playing with better binding, security etc.